# WebView не видит изменений в коде HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, android-webview

WebView читает локальный index.html с внутренний памяти приложения. в этот index.html подключается рядом лежащий app.js обычным

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

в ходе работы приложения app.js изменяется. есть кнопка, которая просто перезагружает WebView.

проблема: на 1 устройстве (на остальных все ок), изменения в app.js не происходят. WebView словно кэширует весь код и в упор не видит изменений.

```
web.clearCache(true);
```

Если чистить кэш перед перезагрузкой страницы, то все работает отлично. вот только кэш в приложение должно наоборот кэшировать данные, поэтому этот вариант отпадает.

Как заставить WebView считать заново весь код, не очищая при этом кэш самой страницы (картинки)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***заменил*** `<script src="app.js"></script>` на

```
<script>
  var url = 'app.js';
  var oldScript = document.getElementById(url);
  if (oldScript)
    oldScript.remove();
  var scr = document.createElement('script');
  scr.id = url;
  scr.src = url + '?t=' + Math.random();
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scr);
  scr.onload = callback;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сделать это после изменения текста скрипта

```js
[...document.scripts]
  .filter(s => ~s.src.indexOf('app.js'))
  .pop().src = 'app.js?' + Date.now()
```

```html
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: не совсем понял, куда именно это вставлять? в index.html или в сам app.js ?

Comment: добавьте в конец body <script>...</script>

Comment: не помогает.....

Comment: @Wlad ну в общем я вижу Вы сами справились

Comment: вроде бы да. если есть корректировки - с радостью приму.

Comment: @Wlad ну в целом идею Вы уловили, я не стал уж сразу все предлагать, но следующим шагом было бы именно то, что Вы описали, изъять старый скрипт и добавить новый, а заставить не кэшировать - это старый способ, причем некоторое сетевое оборудование прошлых веков, только таким cachebreaker-ом пробивалось

Comment: проблема в том, что телефон довольно новый xiaomi redmi 4x. причем у товарища точно такой же телефон и у него такой проблемы нет в приложении. спасибо за подсказку!)

Comment: @Wlad а скрипты локально лежат или из сети тянутся?

Comment: локально.......